# sp.js get all lists by content type

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have combed through the sp namespace docs and not found much to go on.

I found this snippet from http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/12134/how-to-get-the-list-content-types-using-csom-in-sharepoint-2.aspx

```
          //// String Variable to store the siteURL
        string siteURL = "http://c4968397007/";

        //// Get the context for the SharePoint Site to access the data
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteURL);

        //// Get the content type collection for the list "Custom"
        ContentTypeCollection contentTypeColl = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Custom").ContentTypes;

        clientContext.Load(contentTypeColl);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        //// Display the Content Type name
        foreach (ContentType ct in contentTypeColl)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ct.Name);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

which will get a a certain lists content type.

My thought is get all lists, then get all their content types, then use their id/title to query the lists for data.
It seems like a ton of work to do in a display template.

Am I on the right path or is there something I'm missing? Any sp wiz out there care to weight in on the new search/js architecture?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a JavaScript library like [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/) or the popular [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/).

I think the syntax of SharepointPlus is simplier and the code would be something like:

```
$SP().lists(function(list) {
  for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    // list[i]['Name'] contains the name of the list
    $SP().list(list[i]['Name']).get(/* something */)
  }
});
```

You said something about the content types. So you may also want to look at [the `info()` function](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/symbols/%24SP%28%29.list.html#.info) and check the field with the name "ContentTypeId".

FYI I created this SharepointPlus library.